# How do you test that a form text field has no value?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, rspec-rails

How do you test for a text form field that has no value such as in the following case:

```
<input class="string required" id="student_name" name="student[name]"
       size="50" type="text" />
```

I know if a value is present you would have:

```
<input class="string required" id="student_name" name="student[name]"
       size="50" type="text" value="John" />
```

and you can to test to make sure the form field is pre-populated with the name "John" with the following:

```
it "should display an enmpty field for the student name" do
  rendered.should have_selector("input", :type => "text",
                                         :name => "student[name]",
                                         :value => "John")
end
```

I tried specifying ":value => nil" but that didn't work.

Documentation on have_selector() is pretty slim so haven't been able to find anything there and have not been able to find any examples via searches (likely searching with the wrong terms).

As per suggestion I also tried `:value => ''` but get the following error message:

```
expected following output to contain a <input type='text' name='vendor[name]' value=''/>
```

When I tried `:value => nil` I got the following error message:

```
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `include?' for nil:NilClass
```

**Answer**
The solution was to use either `:value => ""` or `:value => ""`.

The reason it did not initially work in my case was that I had included both the webrat and capybara gems in my Gemfile.  After removing webrat it worked using both solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but that did not work either.  I updated the original question with the results from trying `:value => ''` and `:value => nil`.

Comment: Your suggestion works now - see my comment below for the suggestion by Sarvesh Kumar Singh.

Answer (score 0):

try specifying the value as ""

```
it "should display an enmpty field for the student name" do
    rendered.should have_selector("input", :type => "text",
                                     :name => "student[name]",
                                     :value => "")
end
```

Comment: Thanks.  This worked but it looks like the root cause of my problem was that I was including both the webrat and capybara gems in my Gemfile.  I removed webrat and was able to test successfuly with both `:value => ""` as well as `:value => ''`.

Answer (score 0):

What @Unixmonkey said in the comment should work. You can also do:

```
page.first(:css, "#student_name")[:value].should be_nil
```

**Edit** Oh I guess @Unimonkey's comment didn't work according to your update, but the above will work - I've tested it out.

**Edit 2 Re: Comments** Try this instead since you're in a view spec:

```
selector = css_select("#student_name").first
selector["value"].should be_nil
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and get the following error: `NameError: undefined local variable or method 'page' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x0000012a8868c0>`

Comment: Odd. You're using Rspec and Capybara, right? Hmmm, is this in a view spec or a request spec?

Comment: Yes.  Using Rspec and Capybara.  This is in a view spec:  `new.html.erb_spec.rb`

Comment: Oh I see. Yes `page` is only available in request specs. My apologies, I should have asked first. See my new edit.

Comment: No problem.  Thanks for the suggestion.  Please see my comment to the suggestion by Sarvesh Kumar Singh to see the root problem I had as well as the solution.

Comment: You're welcome! Glad you got the answer! Be sure to mark it as the answer so that others with the same problem will know the solution!